# How do you optimise a session-summary workflow for roleplay sessions on Discord?

Tags: tools, online-resources, session-summaries

To create session summaries, I prefer using congregated individual session data. The data I focus on is the number of events, their corresponding dice-rolls, and chat messages to the next event. This workflow enables me to work faster and more conveniently than having all sessions' data in one place.

I currently export Discords channel-chat-logs from the beginning to the end of a session via the [Discord History Tracker](https://github.com/chylex/Discord-History-Tracker). Unfortunately, the output comes in a format that isn't easy for transferring the data to an .ods sheet, so I end up copying many things manually, which is more work than I can reasonably afford to put in.

I browse all these session text logs manually and manually define what counts as an event, and I manually determine which dice rolls correspond to that event. I do not use any preset markers that denote things such as "events" or "rolls," but each roll has the string "roll" in it. This is an output example of the .txt that the Discord History Tracker generates, for anonymity I obscured information by replacing it with "numbers, username1, username2, numbers-representing-user-id, servername, type-name, text-message, and text-message-with dice-roll" :

`{"meta":{"users":{"numbers":{"name":"username1"},"numbers-representing-user-id":{"name":"username2"}},"userindex":["numbers","numbers"],"servers":[{"name":"servername","type":"type-name"}],"channels":{"numbers":{"server":0,"name":"servername"}}},"data":{"numbers":{"numbers":{"u":0,"t":numbers,"m":"text-message"},"numbers":{"u":0,"t":numbers,"m":"text-message-with dice-roll"},`

So with "the number of events, their corresponding dice-rolls, and chat messages to the next event." on your mind: How do you optimise a session-summary workflow for roleplay sessions on Discord?

Comment: This sounds like a scripting problem.  Like, you need to write a script to solve the problem.  If you have a fixed format that you want to change into a different fixed format, that's definitely something you could write some code to do.  But, not knowing what the output from the History Tracker looks like, and what you want to turn it into, it's hard to say if that's sufficient.

Comment: @Tal essentially, the output is a .txt. The tool lets you visualise and search in an accessible manner. I'm sure that there is a better way to do this - it is simply the process that I have done so far.

Comment: I'm probably going in the same direction as Tal is going. But how comfortable are you with making your own tools? For example, if an answer gave a basic proof of concept of a python script to convert text to spreadsheet, how useful is it to you?

Comment: What I'm mostly looking for is : if you need (or can benefit ) from another scripted tools. How comfortable are you with modifying it?

Comment: Also, i think an example of chat history would be useful to see what kind of text we have. For ex. Is there garbage? What kind of  identification tag or formatting to you have to seperate events from garbage? How to you report or roll those dices you want to log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123037/discussion-between-akixkisu-and-3c273).

Comment: What is your output supposed to be like? Your question sounds similar to something I’m in the process of doing, maybe.